# rethinkdb: error while loading shared libraries: libprotobuf.so.17: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: rethinkdb

I have been trying to start rethinkdb but I get the above error on the terminal
Any leads on the solution? I have tried several solutions including uninstalling and reinstalling rethinkdb with no success

Answer (score 0):

Check the you protobuf version.

```
ls /usr/lib/ -all | grep libprotobuf
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       21 dez 26 11:28 libprotobuf.so -> libprotobuf.so.17.0.0
```

Protobuf 3.7 comes with libprotobuf.so.18, but 3.6 has the libprotobuf.so.17.

In my case i downgraded to the protobuf-3.6.1.3-1 and rethinkdb works fine, but probably needs more test to check if any other software is affected.